# Mandarin Equivalent: "duh!"

Tags: translation

"duh!"

**Advanced English Dictionary**

> duh
>
> Disdainful indication that something is obvious.
>
> "It’s hot in the desert. - Well, duh!"

Is there a Mandarin equivalent of 'duh!'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is:

> 废话

Example:

```
A: You know what, a banana without the skin is more tasteful!
B: 废话。
```

废话 is not a good word for kids to imitate, though. And it is rarely used between strangers or to your parents, as it may be impolite/offensive.

Comment: That's more of a equivalent of "bullshit".

Comment: Nope, this is NOT equivalent to "bullshit" because bullshit means a negative response. But this means a positive response, like "Of course you idiot". When one says "bullshit", he/she tries to deny. But when one says "废话", it means "Of course. It is apparent. Can't you see?" In the context, "duh" means exactly "Of course you idiot", so "废话" is a perfect interpretation.

Comment: @Cheng 'bullshit' is 胡说, which indicates an incorrect statement, while 废话 means stating the obvious/unnecessary but correct thing.

Comment: Sorry. You guys are right.

Answer (score 3):

use 废话,那还用说,很明显啊,很显然啊,when speaking to your buddy.
嗯,是啊,确实,when speaking to your college or someone in a formal situation.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no equivalent to "duh".

Chinese does have "hmm" and "errr".

Answer (score 2):

咄 (duo1) should be the one.

In some places of China people also pronounce it as (qü4) to comment on an action perceived as foolish or stupid, or a statement perceived as obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna reply with blame:
废话

If you don't wanna break your relationship with the other one,you can use the word:
呵呵
It gives hint to the other one that "It's a stupid question but I choose to stay as stupid as you."

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues often say :
`"嗯哼～"`,"Uh huh"
`"显然"`,"obviously"
`"然后呢"`,is not in literal meaning "Then what?" ,it means that you have said is not enough,barely nothing. And the speaker doesn't really want you to continue,like you don't have the answer.